# What exactly is giant covalent molecule?

Tags: molecular-structure, molecules, covalent-compounds

What exactly is the definition of "*giant covalent molecule*"? All sources online don't give a definition but instead, allude to properties of examples of giant covalent molecules (such as diamond and graphite). What does the "giant" mean?

To this end, is table sugar (sucrose, $\ce{C12H22O11}$) a giant covalent molecule? I reckon that since it is a covalent compound with a crystalline structure, it should be a giant covalent molecule. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No. It is a small molecule. Ten times that big is still small. Pretty much all compounds have crystalline structure. This is irrelevant.

Comment: Some expressions do not have explicit and unique definition, like a "giant person". Stay with meanings of "giant", "covalent" and "molecule". BTW, it is not fructose, but sucrose.  Is sucrose molecule at least as big as molecules of polysacharides, proteins and DNA to be a giant candidate ?

Comment: @Poutnik My apologies, I meant sucrose; edited that part of the question. So the whole idea of "*giant* covalent molecule" is pretty much arbitrary?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I was under the (probably erroneous) assumption that since table salt is a crystalline lattice structure and is considered giant, table sugar would also fall into this camp since it is a crystal. Does it mean that being a *crystalline lattice structure* is not a sufficient condition in determining the size of the compound?

Comment: @Poutnik Oh ok, I get it now. Thank you for explaining! I'm quite new to chemistry so pardon my confusion over simple questions like this.

Comment: Comments moved to the answer.

Comment: Table salt is just a salt like a thousand others. There is nothing giant about it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The giant covalent molecule (GCM) in your context is a molecule ( 3D for diamonds, 2D for graphite ), which size is more or less (breaks are possible) limited just by the size of the particular solid phase region.

If sucrose molecules were interconnected by covalent bonds forming in the ideal case a single molecular structure of the size of the whole crystal, than it would be a GCM. But they are not. Sucrose crystals are formed by independent molecules. ( Table salt is a ionic compound, it does not form covalent molecules.)

[Wikipedia.org - Covalent_bond -Covalent_structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond#Covalent_structures) says:

> There are several types of structures for covalent substances, including individual molecules, molecular structures, macromolecular structures and giant covalent structures.
> .......
> Network covalent structures (or giant covalent structures) contain large numbers of atoms linked in sheets (such as graphite), or 3-dimensional structures (such as diamond and quartz). These substances have high melting and boiling points, are frequently brittle, and tend to have high electrical resistivity. Elements that have high electronegativity, and the ability to form three or four electron pair bonds, often form such large macromolecular structures.

Comment: I know table salt is an ionic compound; I was just thinking of "since table salt has a *crystalline lattice structure* and is considered to be *giant*, maybe 'crystalline lattice structure' is a sufficient condition for being a 'giant'" and extrapolated 'giant' to covalent molecules. I know now that it doesn't simply work that way. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Comment: @Tham Here, «crystalline lattice structure» merely refers to the *regular* spatial arrangement of the molecules: ideally, 1) it is possible to define a tiny parallelepiped (the [unit cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_cell)) about the shape of the molecules, their orientation and distance to their closets neighbors. Then 2) any other location may be described by this unit cell, because the crystal is built from identical unit cells placed next to/on top of this reference unit cell by translation (similar to stacking shoe boxes), regardless if molecule(s) in this box is/are big, or small.